# how can I delete the element in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I want to create simple application with react js, which should show the users in the display and then when I click on the delete button, it should delete the following item, however I am having some errors.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => {
        setUsers(users);
      })
  }, [users]);

  const deleteMe = () => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
      return prevState.filter(e => e.name)
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div> {user.name}
              <button onClick={deleteMe}> Delete </button>
              {/* <button onClick={}> Update </button> */}
            </div>
          </>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I dont know reactjs but this line is only checking if name has value return it " return prevState.filter(e => e.name )"
can you not some how pass the user value which you want to remove 
Example:
deleteMe = (user) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
        return prevState.filter(e => e.name !== user.name )
    })

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @Hayko - that solution will work if you replace the `onClick={deleteMe}` with `onClick={() => deleteMe(user)}`

Comment: It works, however when I delete the element, the page is being refreshed and the deleted element appears again in the browser

Comment: That’s because your button is probably embedded in a form element and is causing the page to be reloaded as it submits the form. Use `type="button"`

Comment: why don't you use Array.splice(user's index, 1 [number of elements to be deleted], [third one if you want to replace it with another element]).
 this will also be better for performance, because you wouldn't irritate on the array just to remove one item.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

To remove the user, the callback (`onClick`) must have enough information to identify the user to be removed.

In this example, you have some options:

1. Remove by name. Only if the user names are unique:

```
const deleteMe = (userName) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
        return prevState.filter(e => e.name !== userName)
    })
}

return (
    <>
        {users.map((user) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <div> {user.name}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteMe(user.name)}> Delete </button>
                    {/* <button onClick={}> Update </button> */}
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        })}
    </>
)
```

2. Remove by the element itself. Only if the element isn't repeated in the array (the object itself):

```
const deleteMe = (user) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
        return prevState.filter(e => e !== user)
    })
}

return (
    <>
        {users.map((user) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <div> {user.name}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteMe(user)}> Delete </button>
                    {/* <button onClick={}> Update </button> */}
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        })}
    </>
)
```

3. Remove by the array index. Only if the state is an array, usually:

```
const deleteMe = (userIndex) => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
        return prevState.filter((e, i) => i !== userIndex)
    })
}

return (
    <>
        {users.map((user, i) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <div> {user.name}
                    <button onClick={() => deleteMe(i)}> Delete </button>
                    {/* <button onClick={}> Update </button> */}
                    </div>
                </>
            )
        })}
    </>
)
```

See how a second parameter `i` was added to the `map` and `filter` functions. That is usually ignored, but it may be useful sometimes.

As this method may fail if the array is reordered of an element is added/removed between the render and the callback, I wouldn't recommend it unless there is no other alternative.

Comment: bro my problem is not connected with deleting the element, my problem is connected with refreshing, when I want to delete the element, the page refreshs

Comment: it's not refresh, API call hitting continuously when i use your code, please check that

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `useEffect` code. Because you have `users` as a dependency the effect will pick up any changes to that state. State changes, you make an API call, then update `users`, the effect gets called again on the next render, you update `users` in state, `users` gets updated again... etc.

It sounds like you just need an empty dependency array so that the effect is only called once when the component is rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((users) => {
      setUsers(users);
    })
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , element get deleted and not refresh

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Example = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const data = await response.json();
    setUsers(data);
    // .then()
    // .then(users => {
    //   setUsers(users);
    // });
  };
  const deleteMe = index => {
    setUsers(prevState => {
      console.log(prevState);
      return prevState.filter((e, i) => i !== index);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {' '}
            {user.name}
            <button onClick={() => deleteMe(i)}> Delete </button>
            {/* <button onClick={}> Update </button> */}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: good answer but it can be better by moving fetchData function outside the component. because every time the component renders it will re define the function. then add fetchData  to useEffect dependence.

----- another way -----
also it should be placed before it's called.
const fetchData = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    const data = await response.json();
    setUsers(data);
  },[])

also you will need to add it to useEffect's deps